# How to find where implicit functions are continuous?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have this function:
$$
 f(x,y) =   \frac{x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
Where would it be continuous? I really cant find anything by googling. If someone can help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You have not defined the function at the origin. At all other points it is continuous.

Comment: This is explicit function. And why googling? Have you any textbook to read about?

Answer (score 0):

@Kavi Rama Murthy answered your question.

Also, think where this function could have problems? What's happens if the denominator of the fraction becomes zero,  $x^{2}+y^{2}=0 \iff (x,y)=(0,0)$? If you can see that the function would have continuity problems there, then you can see that the function $f$ is continuous for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the definition of continuity for a function with more than one variable? It is a "natural" extension of concept with one variable.

Assume that the domain of  is $D$, then $f:D\to R$. We say that $f$ is continuous in $D$ if for all $(a,b)\in D$ it is the case that:

1. $f(a,b)$ exists;
2. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}f(x,y)$ exists;
3. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}f(x,y)=f(a,b)$.

Clearly this function is not continuous at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: What does "$f(a,b)$ exists" mean? I thought $f$ is defined on $D$.

Comment: $f(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}$. Just clarified cause if $D=\mathbb{R}$, clearly $f(0,0)$ is not well defined.

Comment: So $f$ is a partial function on $D$?

Comment: Yes. Might as well say $D=\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0)\}$